# Extjs grid loading status not gone after delete

Tags: extjs

I have a delete button to delete from grid. But after delete the grid refresh to get latest data, the loading status keeps persisting there. Below is my delete function. After delete I requery the data. How can I prevent the loading status from keep persisting there in the grid. I tried reload store also but still same result.
Thanks.

```
  function doDel2(btn)
 {
        if(btn == 'yes')
        { 
    var m = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
    var jsonData = "[";
          for(var i = 0, len = m.length; i < len; i++){          
     var ss = "{\"id\":\"" + m[i].get("0") + "\"}";
     //alert(ss);
     if(i==0)
               jsonData = jsonData + ss ;
        else
      jsonData = jsonData + "," + ss; 
     //ds.remove(m[i]);   
          } 
    jsonData = jsonData + "]";
    store.load({params:{start:0, delData:jsonData}}); 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you creating JSON data by manipulating strings?  Ext.util.JSON, maybe?  You need more code here to make a real question.  For instance, where the hell does your "store" reference come from?  Is doDel2() run in the scope of your gridpanel, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line before `store.load`:

```
store.on('load', function() {grid.getView().refresh()});
```